# Downloading File From Internet On Android Programming

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I'm new on Android programming and i want to download files from internet but this code dont work.
This is my class that contains public variables:

```
public class G extends Application{
public static Context context;
public static final String             
    SD=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
public static final String SD_path= SD +"/file-downloader";
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    context=this.getApplicationContext();
    new File(SD_path).mkdirs();
}

}
```

and my downloader class:

```
public class FileDownloader {
public static void download(String address,String Path)
{
    try {
        FileOutputStream output=new FileOutputStream(Path);
        byte[] buffer =new byte[8*1024];
        URL url =new URL(address);
        HttpURLConnection connection =(HttpURLConnection)  
                    url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.connect();



        InputStream stream=connection.getInputStream();
        int len =0;
        while((len=stream.read(buffer))  >0)
        {
            output.write(buffer,0,len);
        }
                    output.close();



    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
```

My main class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FileDownloader.download("http://192.168.1.2/file-server/image1.jpg", 
            G.SD_path+"/img2.jpg");
}
```

Everything is ok but i dont know why this code dont work!
all permissions added to manifest and wamp server work fine,but error happens on 
==> Connection.connect(); <== Line.
Thanks for Any Help

My Logcat Errors:

```
06-09 17:00:09.665: E/AndroidRuntime(793): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start     
activity ComponentInfo{com.test.download/com.test.download.MainActivity}:  
android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

06-09 17:00:09.665: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at   
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)

06-09 17:00:09.665: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at  
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)

06-09 17:00:09.665: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at 
com.test.download.FileDownloader.download(FileDownloader.java:23)

06-09 17:00:09.665: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at    
com.test.download.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
```

Comment: Where did you find this code?

Comment: Post your Logcat errors

Comment: Either do the Downloading task using Threads or AsyncTask. download method should be called from either of the above.

Comment: Thanks For Help,With using new Thread it work Fine .

Answer (score 0):

You are trying network connection on UI thread. Try [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for downloading.